Datatables detener evento paginación
Tengo un Datatable con paginación.
Necesito que al pulsar sobre cualquier botón de la paginación haga una comprobación y en el caso que falle no realizar el cambio de página y no recargar el Datatable.
Tengo esto definido para localizar el evento:
drawCallback: function (settings) {
        const table = this.api()
        $('.paginate_button.next:not(.disabled)', table.table().container())
          .on('click', function (e) {
            if (limit.length > 0) {
              alert('Error.')
              e.stopPropagation()
            }
          })
        // Event handler for page number buttons
        $('.paginate_button:not(.next, .previous)', table.table().container())
          .on('click', function (e) {
             if (limit.length > 0) {
              alert('Errors.')
              e.stopPropagation(e)
            }
          })
        // Event handler for the "Previous" button
        $('.paginate_button.previous:not(.disabled)', table.table().container())
          .on('click', function (e) {
             if (limit.length > 0) {
              alert('Error.')
              e.stopPropagation()
            }
          })
      },

Muestra el mensaje, pero recarga el datatable
¿alguna idea que me pueda ayudar?
Gracias

Y el preventDefault() lo has probado en lugar del stopPropagation() o antes del mismo?  Quizás te lo pare

No no lo he probado, pero he encontrado otra solución

He encontrado la siguiente solución sustituyendo "e.stopPropagation()" por:
$table.settings()[0].jqXHR.abort()

Siendo $table $table = $('#mitabla').DataTable()
